# Copy-item create directory on single file copy

Tags: powershell-2.0

I'm trying to copy a single file using copy-item to a remote computer using powershell.  It works fine if the directory already exists but fails if it doesn't.  I know -force works if it is a directory to a directory but fails if it's a single file.  Is there a way to get copy-item to create the destination path without doing a test-path and new-item?

```
copy-item "\\server1\Upgrade.exe" "\\computer1\c$\temp\" -Force
```

Edit: I just decided to go with xcopy.  Seems to work better.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I did eventually get this to work by doing the following

```
Copy-Item "\\server1\Upgrade.exe" -Destination "\\chomputers1\c$\temp" -Force
```

Comment: Does this work like you expected?  I would think this would copy the Upgrade.exe to a file named temp, not into the temp folder.  I still don't know how to copy a file, creating the directory if required.

Comment: Confirmed Foson's comment

Comment: Confirmed Cimplicity's comment on foson's comment.

Answer (score 6):

In PowerShell 2.0, it is still not possible to get the Copy-Item cmdlet to create the destination folder, you'll need code like this:

```
$destinationFolder = "C:\My Stuff\Subdir"

# Copy-Item will not create the destination folder by itself.
if (!(Test-Path -path $destinationFolder)) {New-Item $destinationFolder -Type Directory}
Copy-Item "\\server1\Upgrade.exe" -Destination $destinationFolder
```

If you use -Recurse in the Copy-Item it will create all the subfolders of the source structure in the destination but it won't create the actual destination folder, even with -Force.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Copy-Item without the -Destination nor -Force cmdlet but using full path for your destination.